# load model from folder in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and handing admin side and users side separately. now i have model which is in admin folder and i want to call in controller of users. but when i am trying to load model from admin folder

```
$this->load->model('admin/myinterest_model');

$data['myInterest'] = $this->myinterest_model->selectResult('user',  $this->session->userdata['Id']);
```

it shows following error

```
Message: Undefined property: Users::$myinterest_model
Filename: controllers/users.php
```

Please guide me how to load model from admin

Comment: Where are you using this model? In a controller? What is the class definition of this controller?

Comment: @abs class Users extends CI_Controller {
}
this file is placed in controller but myinterest_model in placed in admin/models/ so i need to access model function in users controller

Comment: show your model details, you may have name typo in the class def.

Comment: class MyInterest_Model extends CI_Model {
 
        private $tablename = 'my_interests';
 function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }
}
its working fine when i am loading this model in admin folder but when i am trying to one step back folder it shows above eror

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this call constructor in controller and load model into it

```
function __construct()
    {
        // Initialization of class
        parent::__construct();

        // load the model
        $this->load->model('admin/myinterest_model');
    }
```

Comment: while a valid solution this isn't an answer, you are loading the model in construct or function, same thing.

Comment: i know but do you have construct method in model and controller because its compulsory. i got same error because my controller have not a construct method

Answer (score 21):

```
$this->load->model('admin/myinterest_model' , 'myinterest');
```

The second parameter (optional) is used to call the method.

ex:

```
$this->myinterest->get_users();
```

Answer (score 0):

create a folder inside your **models** folder *(application/models/admin)* and put your admin files in there *(**M**yinterest_model.php)*
now in your controller just call your model

```
$this->load->model('admin/myinterest_model');
```

Comment: i have already added myinterest_model in admin folder but now i need to access a function from admin/myinterest_model in user controller so when i try to load model as you mention it didn't works